# How to set autocommit in a Redshift SQL Session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am connecting to AWS Redshift with a browser-based client JackDB.

and try to run vacuum

```
VACUUM table_name;
```

of course get the following error

```
ERROR: VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block
```

how can I set autocommit in SQL session, is there something in Redshift like

```
set autocommit=on;
VACUUM table_name;
set autocommit=off;
```

P.S.

the official client recommended in Redshift documentation is SQL Workbench/J. It has the functionality "autocommit" to ensure the successful running of VACUUM command.

but JackDB is more convinient and portable

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
END;
VACUUM table_name;
BEGIN;
```

Comment: receive the same error: ERROR: VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block

Comment: Try this :

END;
set autocommit=on;
VACUUM table_name;
COMMIT;
set autocommit=off;

Answer (score 0):

END; set autocommit=on; VACUUM table_name; COMMIT; set autocommit=off;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your attempt to help. You could improve your answer by adding some explanation to your code quote. You might also want to improve readability by using formatting options. Getting the badge for taking the [tour] will probably support you in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to just check the autocommit check box in the connection manager.